# how to change the time of a ZKTeco Biometric zkemkeeper.dll c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, zkteco

I request your help. I have a bioface 2 device and I am working with the ZKTECO.DLL called **zkemkeeper.dll** and I need to be able to change the date and time of the device from **C#**.

but I have no idea how to do it ...

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, few are going to write any code for you. The idea is that you give it a try and then come back with specific questions related to your [mcve]. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In order to change date and time of the device using the zkemkeeper.dll you just need to call the following method:

```
SetDeviceTime2(deviceId, year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Please, note that this answers specifically to your question on how to update the date and time for ZKTeco devices... In order to learn how to import the dll, connect and disconnect from the device you should take a look at the documentation or the source code provided with the SDK.

You can download the latest SDK, demo and documentation from the following link:

https://www.zkteco.com/en/index/Service/load/id/674.html

Best regards.